# подскажите пожалуйста,vs code 2019 не показыет ошибки в рабочей области,хотя даю явные ошибки

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

уже многое перепробовал : скидывал настройки,лазил в настройках и читал всякое в инете.Буду благодарен за помощь!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мои плагины

Comment: а плагины для с++ подключены?

Comment: да.там у меня все работало еще все с утра.Я комб клавиш нажал какую-то и все @KoVadim

Comment: плагины выше фото

Comment: А в самих файлах лазил: глобальном settings файле и пользовательском, конкретно по ключу "C_Cpp". Если что осталось, то самое простое убрать все строки.

Comment: а компилировать/запускать свое творение пробовали?

Comment: да,если нету ошибок,то все компилит.Но я специально делаю явные ошибки но они не появляються в рабочей области @KoVadim

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg только что вроде все удалил но все-равно не работает

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg а нет, все-таки помогло!спасибо!

Comment: @egor У меня однажды было хуже, пришлось ручками все удалять из каталога расширений, кешей,, переустанавливать и перенастраивать.

Comment: и такое бывает) @AlexanderLonberg